# Ionic 5 Input type number with up / down increment arrows

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic5

I am using Ionic 5 in a project.
One thing I need is an input type number with up / down increment arrows like this image:

[image]

How can I do that as I cannot see any examples of that on the UI Components on their website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `type` attribute of `ion-input` to "number":

```
<ion-input type="number" value="5" min="1" max="9"></ion-input>
```